# SQL insert: ignore bad records

Tags: database, database-design, triggers

How can I configure my insert statement in SQL Server as shown below so that the good rows are created in the table instead of none of the rows being created at all?

```
CREATE TABLE sql_server_test_a 
( 
    ID         NVARCHAR(4000), 
    FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(200), 
    LAST_NAME  NVARCHAR(200),
    Member_ID  INT
); 

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME,  LAST_NAME, Member_ID) 
VALUES ('1', 'Paris', 'Hilton', twelve),
       ('2', 'Nicky', 'Hilton', 24);
```

Comment: You can't - `insert` statement either works entirely or does nothing. Same for triggers - you can't exclude some rows from inserted (well, you could delete them after successful insert - but this likely doesn't help you). Where your invalid values come from? You should deal with these _before_ insertion.

Comment: Would you use a Trigger or Check to check before insertion?

Comment: Your application should ensure that the information is valid before you try any SQL INSERTS.